# RxJava and rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException exception

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to get a very basic RxJava based application to work. I have defined the following Observable class which reads and returns lines from a file:

```
public Observable<String> getObservable() throws IOException
    {
        return Observable.create(subscribe -> {
            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/trial.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            String line = null;
            try {
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    subscribe.onNext(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                subscribe.onError(e);
            }
            finally {
                subscribe.onCompleted();
            }
        });
    }
```

Next I have defined the subscrober code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() ->
        {
            RxObserver observer = new RxObserver();
            try {
                observer.getObservable()
                        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe( x ->System.out.println(x),
                                    t -> System.out.println(t),
                                    () -> System.out.println("Completed"));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        thread.start();
        thread.join();
    }
```

The file has close to 50000 records. When running the app I am getting "rx.exceptions.MissingBackpressureException". I have gone through some of the documentation and as suggested, I tried added the ".onBackpressureBuffer()" method in the call chain. But then I am not getting the exception but the completed call too isin't getting fired.

What is the right way to handle scenario wherein we have a fast producing Observable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that your readLine logic ignores backpressure. You can apply `onBackpressureBuffer()` just before `observeOn` to start with but there is a recent addition `SyncOnSubscribe` that let's you generate values one by one and takes care of backpressure:

```
SyncOnSubscribe.createSingleState(() => {
    try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/trial.txt");
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
},
(s, o) -> {
    try {
        String line = s.readLine();
        if (line == null) {
            o.onCompleted();
        } else {
            o.onNext(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        s.onError(ex);
    }
},
s -> {
    try {
       s.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
});
```

The second problem is that your Thread will complete way before all elements on the io thread has been delivered and thus the main program exits. Either remove the `observeOn`, add `.toBlocking` or use a `CountDownLatch`.

```
RxObserver observer = new RxObserver();
try {

    CountDownLatch cdl = new CountDownLatch(1);

    observer.getObservable()
           .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .subscribe( x ->System.out.println(x),
                       t -> { System.out.println(t); cdl.countDown(); },
                       () -> { System.out.println("Completed"); cdl.countDown(); });

    cdl.await();
 } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Is SyncOnSubscribe part of the most recent RxJava package? I am having the 1.0.8 version of RxJava framework?

Comment: Got it. Included the latest version 1.1.0 and it included the SyncOnSubscribe class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is *observeOn* operator, since each Observer's onNext() call is scheduled to be called on a separate thread, your Observable keeps producing those scheduled calls in a loop regardless of subscriber (observeOn) capacity.

If you keep this synchronous, Observable will not emit next element until subscriber is done with the previous one, since it's all done on a one thread and you will not have backpressure problems anymore.

If you still want to use *observeOn*, you will have to implement backpressure logic in your Observable's *OnSubscribe#call* method

Comment: this is quite old but getting rid of observeOn solved backpressure for me, can you please elaborate more why this works? I can feel that an observable should be able do the same  with multiple threads